# Clicking a button within an iframe with puppeteer

Tags: iframe, puppeteer

Trying to click on the "I accept all cookies" button which is inside iFrame (The popup only show for EU country ip).
You can check here also jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=VgKpE0jfJF.

[image]

```
//index.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless:false,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      slowMo: 50,
      args: ['--window-size=1440,900', '--disable-gpu', "--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process", '--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=true']
    });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.oracle.com/cloud/cost-estimator.html');

  await page.waitFor(3000)
  const frame = page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'iframe');
  const acceptBtn = await frame.$(`a[class="call"]`);
  await acceptBtn.click();

  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  //await browser.close();
})();
```

The error i get

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined
    at
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this iframe has no name in the HTML code, so you can try its src (URL):

```js
const frame = page.frames().find(f => f.url().startsWith('https://consent-pref.trustarc.com/'));
```